# Kotlin encapsulating multiple 3rd party interfaces into one

Tags: kotlin

Third party library library:

- cannot be modified
- service type library

```
interface I3rdParty1 {
  fun fun1(): Int?
  fun fun2()
  //...
  fun funA()
  fun funB()
  //...
}

interface I3rdParty2 {
  fun fun1(): Int?
  fun fun2()
  //...
  fun funX()
  fun funY()
  //...
}

class Service() {
  fun getService1(): I3rdParty1
  fun getService2(): I3rdParty2
}
```

Notes:

- Both have the same common set of function signatures.
- No function with the same name but different signature.
- Only one of the service will be available and not both.
- There are about 10 common ones and about 5 unique ones on both interfaces.

In my code the goal is to encapsulate both services and merge them into one or something. Without adding boilerplate code.

```
interface MyService extends I3rdParty1, I3rParty2 {
  // Can I not write all 15 common ones and 2x5 uniques ones here?
}

class MyCode() : MyService {
  var service1: I3rdParty1? = null
  var service2: I3rdParty2? = null
  
  fun detectService() {
    service1 = Service().getService1()
    service2 = Service().getService2()
  }

  // Is there a way to simplify this?

  override fun1(): Int? {
    return if (service1 != null)
     service1.fun1()
    else if (service2 != null)
     service2.fun1()
    else null
  }

  override fun2() {
    if (service1 != null)
     service1.fun2()
    else if (service2 != null)
     service2.fun2()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Delegation` pattern.

```kotlin
interface I3rdParty1 {
    fun fun1(): Int?
    fun fun2()
    //...
    fun funA()
    fun funB()
    //...
}

interface I3rdParty2 {
    fun fun1(): Int?
    fun fun2()
    //...
    fun funX()
    fun funY()
    //...
}

class Service() {
    fun getService1(): I3rdParty1
    fun getService2(): I3rdParty2
}

interface MyService : I3rdParty1, I3rdParty2

class MyCode(private val service: Service) : MyService {
    private val service1: I3rdParty1? = service.getService1()
    private val service2: I3rdParty2? = service.getService2()

    override fun fun1(): Int? = service1?.fun1() ?: service2?.fun1()
    override fun fun2() = service1?.fun2() ?: service2?.fun2()
    override fun funA() = service1?.funA() ?: service2?.funA()
    override fun funB() = service1?.funB() ?: service2?.funB()
    override fun funX() = service1?.funX() ?: service2?.funX()
    override fun funY() = service1?.funY() ?: service2?.funY()
}
```

Explanation of `?:`:

```kotlin
service1?.fun1() ?: service2?.fun1()
```

is equivalent to

```kotlin
if (service1 != null) {
    service1.fun1()
} else {
    service2?.fun1()
}
```